Android grey-out notification/disabled notification permissions for 3rd-party apps
I am in desperate need of assistance. I have a bit of tech knowledge but have not had any success with resolving this issue.
I have an S24 Ultra. Two 3rd-party apps have had their notification permissions removed by Android at some point. Again, they are not system apps, still, I do not have the option to enable notifications. One is my son's school app and it is extremely important I receive these notifications. I've seen others with this issue but Samsung has not yet acknowledged the problem. Below are steps I've already tried.
Steps taken:

Both apps are up-to-date

Issue began prior to phone software update; remained after most recent update

Gone into settings to enable notification permissions (not an option)

Gone to "permissions>notifications" directly; neither of two apps appear with "installed" sort. One appears when sorting by 'system' though neither are a system apps. I am able to  toggle the notification on for that one app, however it immediately turns back off (even
if it appears to stay on you will realize upon checking that it did not.)

Have cleared app cache

Have uninstalled and re-installed apps

Have uninstalled apps, cleared phone partition cache, then reinstalled apps

Have "reset all app permissions" in settings ( I do NOT recommend doing this if you are picky about settings as I am)


Of course I am trying hard to not factory reset my phone. People are quick to suggest that, however, for me, that would require a lot of work with everything I have on my phone; so that would be an absolute LAST resort.
I hope someone knows what is going on.

It may be easier to answer you if you would name the two apps your question is about (including Play Store link).

Welcome! You mentioned that you've seen others with this issue. Do you mind providing links to those posts of other people with similar issues?
